# Issue with a fluid form inside a window

Tags: forms, layout, extjs, extjs4.1, fluid

We have to create a fluid layout meeting following conditions:

1. There is a Form inside a Window.
2. If Window Width is increased, then Form Width and its Fields Width should also increase.
3. If Window Width is decreased, then Form Width and its Fields Width should get reduced but only upto a limit.
4. If the Window Width is reduced beyond a limit, then there should appear a scrollbar at the Form.

We tried at this by giving flex to fields and minWidth to the Form, assuming that flex will take care of increase of width and minWidth to form would lead to a scroll if the window width is reduced further.

But this unfortunately is not working as per the following test case:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='resources/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css' />
        <script type='text/javascript' src='resources/extjs/ext-all-dev.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function getForm(){
                var form    =   {
                    xtype:'form',
                    region:'north',
                    height:100,
                    autoScroll:true,
                    minWidth:300,
                    title: 'Simple Form',
                    items: [
                    {
                        xtype:'container',
                        layout:'hbox',
                        items:[
                            {
                                xtype:'textfield',
                                fieldLabel: 'First',
                                name: 'first',
                                allowBlank: false,
                                width:100,
                                labelWidth:50,
                                flex:1
                            },{
                                xtype:'textfield',
                                fieldLabel: 'Last',
                                name: 'last',
                                allowBlank: false,
                                width:100,
                                labelWidth:50,
                                flex:1
                            }
                        ]
                    }]
                };
                return form;
            }
            function getWin(){
                var win =   Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
                    title:'Test Window',
                    height:400,
                    width:600,
                    layout:'border',
                    items:[
                        getForm(),
                        {
                            region:'center',
                            title:'Center Region',
                            html:'Center Region Content'
                        }
                    ]
                });
                return win;
            }
            Ext.onReady(function(){
                var win =   getWin();
                win.show();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this one? Or what is being done wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good example similar to this:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/anchoring.html

Here is a mix of that with your code.  The min and max are set right at the window container.  There is an autoScroll and autoWidth config on the form with a minWidth to scroll if the window is smaller than the width needed for that section.

See it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Du9Nb/

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.window.Window'
]);

Ext.onReady(function() {
    var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        border: false,
        fieldDefaults: {
            labelWidth: 50
        },
        url: 'save-form.php',
                autoScroll: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        bodyPadding: 5,

        items: [
            {xtype:'panel', 
             title:'Simple Form',
             minWidth: 400,
             layout: 'hbox',
             defaultType: 'textfield',
             items:[
            {
              fieldLabel: 'First',
                name: 'first',
                allowBlank: false,
                flex: 1,
                anchor:'100%'  // anchor width by percentage
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Last',
                name: 'last',
                allowBlank: false,
                flex: 1,
                anchor: '100%'  // anchor width by percentage
            }
          ]
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Center Region',
                html: 'Center Region Content'

            }]
    });

    var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Test Window - Resize Me',
        width: 600,
        height:400,
        minWidth: 300,
        minHeight: 200,
        layout: 'fit',
        plain: true,
        items: form,

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Send'
        },{
            text: 'Cancel'
        }]
    });

    win.show();
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the post John and for sharing the sample code. In your code I found that you have added a Panel to a Form. And its the minWidth of this panel which is doing the trick. Now, a form is also already a panel, thus, addition of this panel is introducing an extra branch unfortunately. I had tried adding minWidth to the container which I have used in place of panel in my code, but it didn't have any effect. Looks like, container is not able to maintain the restriction of width the way panel does but it comes with a price of an extra branch. Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: A container will also work in the panels place.  You can also put the minWidth on the container you have that holds the two form elements in your example. Here is your snippet with the minWidth moved http://jsfiddle.net/9bQp7/  This will put the scrollbar in the form section only rather than wrapping all of the window contents.